# laravel variable not passing through Undefined variable $item

Tags: laravel, variables

Hi all can please some one help me with this problem in Laravel 10 trying to pass a variable on a button link I made to pass school id to a other page I have done this before with no problems but I am stuck on this one not sure what's going on please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks

on my blade page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"onclick="window.location.href='{{ route('school.assessment.year', ['schoolId' => $item->id]) }}'">Year 1</button>
```

in my web.php:

```
Route::get('/school/{schoolId}/assessment/year', [EduvantageViewSchoolStatisticsController::class, 'showStudentAssessmentYear'])
    ->name('school.assessment.year');
```

and in my controller:

```
public function someMethodName() {
    $schoolId = session('current_school_id'); 

    $item = EduvantageSchools::find($schoolId);
    if (!$item) {
        abort(404, 'School not found.');
    }

    // Pass the school item to the view
    return view('schoolview.profile.student_assessment_year', compact('item', 'schoolId'));
}
```

I tried a other way but did not work as well making in my AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot(): void
{
    // Bind the schoolID to the container
    $schoolId = session('find_school_id');
    $item = EduvantageSchools::find($schoolId); // Ensure this session variable is being set correctly
    $this->app->instance('schoolID', $schoolId);
}
```

and in my controller:

```
public function showStudentAssessmentYear()
{
    $schoolId = session('find_school_id');
    $item = EduvantageSchools::find($schoolId);
    
    dd($item); // Debug to display $item
    
    return view('schoolview.profile.student_assessment_year', compact('item', 'schoolId'));
}
```

Comment: You have parameter in URL (defined route) but method in controller doesn't expect one.

Comment: how do I fix this please I want the method in controller to expect this

Answer (score -1):

You have  passed argument in your route ie. {schoolId} but not passed the parrameter in your function showStudentAssessmentYear().
it should look like public function showStudentAssessmentYear($schoolId)

Comment: I just tried but still not working                                                                                                 public function showStudentAssessmentYear($schoolId)

Comment: try this if problem is on blade **onclick="window.location='{{ route('school.assessment.year', [$item->id]) }}"**

Comment: What error are you getting can you send it?

Comment: no luck still having the same error Undefined variable $item

Comment: Alright : Please put <a  class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{url('/school/'.$item->id.'/assessment/year')}}">Year 1</button> and put dd(schoolId) on your method. Check if it is coming or not.

Comment: still the same error Undefined variable $item  using ------> <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{url('/school/'.$item->id.'/assessment/year')}}">Year 1</button>

Comment: could it be my web.php how its setup with ----->             Route::get('/school/{schoolId}/assessment/year', [EduvantageViewSchoolStatisticsController::class, 'showStudentAssessmentYear'])->name('school.assessment.year');

Comment: Please chekck if item is coming in someMethodName(). put a dd($item). I believe this** blade file  ** for   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"onclick="window.location.href='{{ route('school.assessment.year', ['schoolId' => $item->id]) }}'">Year 1</button> is coming from  **schoolview.profile.student_assessment_year**?

Comment: no web.php is fine

Comment: The prolem may lay here : someMethodName() if you are loading the button blade file.

Comment: the variable $item is not defined in my ---> blade.php view

Comment: its named ---> showStudentAssessmentYear

Comment: Please try checking the session id in yout duncton @OrlandoClement public function showStudentAssessmentYear()
{
    $schoolId = session('find_school_id'); // dd($schoolId ) find it if it is showing the id and then match it with EduvantageSchools table if it is present there. 
    $item = EduvantageSchools::find($schoolId);
    
    dd($item); // Debug to display $item
    
    return view('schoolview.profile.student_assessment_year', compact('item', 'schoolId'));
}

Comment: no its not sorry for not replying trying to do what you ask but my debug is not showing anything

Comment: I got it working found ---> null // app/Http/Controllers/EduVantage/EduvantageViewSchoolStatisticsController.php:570

Comment: I found the problem it was in my AppServiceProvider.php had to change a few things public function boot(): void
    {
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('schools', EduvantageSchools::all());
        });